# Расстояние между item в ListView

Tags: java, android

Как изменить расстояние между item в listview

Comment: Можно задать высоту разделителя `android:dividerHeight` или программно [`listView.setDividerHeight(int height)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDividerHeight%28int%29). Либо задать отступы в разметке элемента.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/list_view"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:divider="@null"
  android:dividerHeight="8dp"/>
```

те вы создаете пустой разделитель высотой в 8dp, тем самым раздвигая элементы списка. У этого способа есть возможный плюс, он будет работать даже при разных item в 1 списке.